# How to allocate a string using malloc and realloc using C

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, realloc

I am trying to (1) initialize a char array and (2) resize the array every time it reads a string. However, whenever I try to compile, I see the message says that
`error: initializer element is not constant. char *ptr = malloc(1 * sizeof(*ptr));`

I do not understand what's wrong with my codes. I tried both (1) `char *ptr = (char*) malloc(ptr * sizeof(char))` and (2) `char *ptr = malloc(1 * sizeof(*ptr))`, but none of them worked.

Here is my full codes:

```
// char *ptr = (char*) malloc(ptr * sizeof(char));
char *ptr = malloc(1 * sizeof(*ptr));

void execute(char *splitInput)
{
  char myhistory[] = "myhistory";
  int string_length = strlen(splitInput);

  char *new_ptr = realloc(ptr, sizeof(char) * string_length);
 }
```

Comment: The `char` array `myhistory` has no use in `execute()`. Is this intended?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the declaration `char *ptr = malloc(1 * sizeof(*ptr));`.  C doesn't allow code there, only static declarations.  That is:

```
char *ptr = "Foo bar baz.";
```

is fine, because it is assigning a static string.  There is no code to execute.

The following will work:

```
char *ptr;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  // char *ptr = (char*) malloc(ptr * sizeof(char));
  ptr = malloc(1 * sizeof(*ptr));
}

void execute(char *splitInput)
{
  char myhistory[] = "myhistory";
  int string_length = strlen(splitInput);

  char *new_ptr = realloc(ptr, sizeof(char) * string_length);
 }
```

Comment: `  char *ptr = "Foo bar baz.";  ` This is dangerous because the string is not-modifiable. It's an undefined behavior

Answer (score 0):

```
char *ptr = (char*) malloc(ptr * sizeof(char));
char *ptr = malloc(1 * sizeof(*ptr));
```

In C, It is not permissible to execute code, such as the code in functions like `malloc()`, outside of any other function. Thus, those statements will never work regardless of how you rearrange parts of it.

You need to declare the pointer at global scope and do the assignment to the pointer returned by `malloc()` inside of any function:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *ptr;                              // declare ptr as pointer with global scope.

void execute(char *splitInput)
{
  //char myhistory[] = "myhistory";
  int string_length = strlen(splitInput);

  char *new_ptr = realloc(ptr, sizeof(char) * string_length);

  strcpy(ptr,splitInput);
}

int main()
{
   char s[] = "Hello World!";

   ptr = malloc(1 * sizeof(*ptr));       // assign ptr to point to the memory 
                                         // allocated by malloc. 
   execute(s);   
}
```

Note that `myhistory` has no use inside of the function `execute()`.